# Magento - Authorize.net - Get Payment Update for expired transactions

Tags: magento, authorize.net

Magento 1.6.1

I have set up Authorize.net (AIM) for the client's store. Previously they were using saved CC method and entering information manually in Authorize.net's merchant terminal.

Most of it is working as expected, however for transactions that are flagged as 'Suspected Fraud' by Authorize.net, if the client does not update the transaction manually before the authorization expires, using 'Get Payment Update' in Magento fails because the transaction is expired (I believe it's five days for an authorize only transaction).

For the client, it seems the only way to update this order in Magento is to simply delete the order, as it doesn't appear the Paygate model knows about expired transactions. Performing 'Get Payment Update' simply returns 'There is no update for this payment'.

I have already modified the file: `/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorize.net` to have the correct API URL as described in issue #27117 ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=12991 - must be logged in to view ). This resolved the button not working for all other orders; however this does not fix the issue I am describing.

Is anyone familiar with Authorize.net's AIM API so that we can update these orders in Magento to something that makes sense (canceled, etc.) without having to delete the order? I am thinking it should be a case of adding a new order status to Magento, checking the update for an 'Expired' status, and setting the order to the newly created order status.

-- edit --

I just ran a diff for the file mentioned above and noticed that Magento 1.7.0.2 includes the `_isTransactionExpired()` method which seems like it would be the fix. Can it be as simple as updating this model with the newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I manually included the `_isTransactionExpired()` method described in my question to the `app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorize.php`, and things appeared normal and it was seeming to work as expected.

It's now been a month and a half, and I've not had the client come back to tell me things are not working, so I am assuming this fixed the issue.